# SQL Replace Null entry with value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a query/script in MS SQL Server that will do the following:

Table1

| Project | Employee | Date | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 007 | 23-02-01 | Found Bad Guy |
| 1111 | 007 | 23-02-01 | NULL |
| 1112 | 007 | 23-02-18 | Drank Martini |
| 1112 | 007 | 23-02-18 | NULL |

I need a way to replace the `NULL`s with the appropriate comment for that same day, but only if the project/date is the same (not put Martini on the 1111 project).
So the final result should look like this...

| Project | Employee | Date | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 007 | 23-02-01 | Found Bad Guy |
| 1111 | 007 | 23-02-01 | Found Bad Guy |
| 1112 | 007 | 23-02-18 | Drank Martini |
| 1112 | 007 | 23-02-18 | Drank Martini |

I'm not going to know which projects or which dates have the null comment, but would be ok if I have to run it twice if there are two null's for the same date with one having the comment.  I'm only going to be able to search a date range >= '2023-02-01'
I have edited the above to respond to questions and better clarification

Comment: Please also show your desired results. And I suggest investigating `LAG` or another suitable window function that meets your requirements. You don't for example explain whether the null will always follow a non-null value, or whether it could be anywhere within that date. What if if there are multiple non-null values? Which would you pick?

Comment: Modified Question

Comment: What if there are 4 records for a given date and 2 have null values? Which if the non-null values should be chosen? Also have you tried anything?

Comment: So far (and I'm a novice by every definition) I've been unable to modify the 2 answers so far that MS likes them, I was in process of trying to use the Join, but still don't have it correct.
In this scenario, I will correct the 1 out of 10,000 times that occurred where there was 2 answers and 2 nulls, the 9,999 is one answer and one, or two nulls

Comment: Any update statement that updates nulls will also update the case where there are multiple nulls and multiple values, hence you should just define a the rule for us to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
update destination
set destination.comment = source.comment
from your_table destination
join your_table source on source.project = destination.project
                      and source.date = destination.date
                      and source.comment is not null
where destination.comment is null
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had said MS SQL, not just SQL

Comment: @FreddyKrugler this works with SQL server

Comment: I wasn't replacing my info correctly, this one is the winner.

Answer (score 0):

Just updating some NULL values..

First determine the new value for that column

```sql
SELECT 
   Project,
  Employee,
  Date,
  CASE WHEN Comment is NULL THEN LAG(Comment) OVER (PaRTITION BY Project,Date ORDER BY Employee) ELSE Comment END as Comment
FROM mytable;
```

and use this query in an UPDATE statement:

```sql
UPDATE mytable 
SET Comment = x.Comment
FROM mytable m
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT 
      Project,
      Employee,
      Date,
      CASE WHEN Comment is NULL THEN LAG(Comment) OVER (PaRTITION BY Project,Date ORDER BY Employee) ELSE Comment END as Comment
   FROM mytable
  ) x on x.Project = m.Project and x.Employee = m.Employee and x.Date = m.Date
WHERE m.Comment IS NULL
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/FtpCURKL)

Answer (score -1):

**Its works with mysql and postgres**
Scenario 1:Nested Query works with postgres and mysql

```
update your_table as s set comment =(
select comment from your_table  where project=s.project and date=s.date and comment is not null limit 1
)
where s.comment is null;
```

Scenario 2:Using Join works with mysql

```
UPDATE your_table d
JOIN your_table s ON s.date =d.date and s.project=d.project 
SET    d.comment = s.comment 
where d.comment is null 
and s.comment is not null
```

Scenario 3:works with MIcrosoft SQL Server tested on this [Site](https://onecompiler.com/sqlserver)

```
update your_table set comment =(
select top 1 comment from your_table as t  where project=your_table.project and date=your_table.date
and comment is not null
)
where your_table.comment is null;
```

Scenario 4:This join is also works with Microsoft Server tested on [this](https://onecompiler.com/sqlserver) Site

```
UPDATE st
SET st.comment = sc.comment
FROM your_table AS st
JOIN your_table AS sc
ON st.Project = sc.Project and st.date = sc.date
WHERE sc.Comment is not null
AND st.Comment is  null
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had said MS SQL, not just SQL

Comment: Neither solution works with SQL server .